# Editar status de vários registros com checkbox marcado?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, checkbox

Preciso enviar um array com os id dos registros que tiverem o checkbox marcado, para editar de uma só vez o campo status.
Nota1: todos registros sofrerão a mesma alteração listada em um select.
Nota2: consigo editar cada registro individualmente através de um link com o seu id respectivo.

```
<form action="<?php echo current_url(); ?>" id="formExportacao" method="post" class="form-horizontal" >
  <?php echo form_hidden('idExportacao',$result->idExportacao) ?>
     <div class="control-group">

<div class="control-group">
   <label for="status" class="control-label"><span class="required">Status*</span></label>
    <div class="controls">
       <select class="span3" name="status" id="status" value="">
       <option <?php if($result->status == 'Faturado'){echo 'selected';} ?> value="Faturado">Faturado</option>                      
       <option <?php if($result->status == 'Finalizado'){echo 'selected';} ?> value="Finalizado">Finalizado</option>
       <option <?php if($result->status == ''){echo 'selected';} ?> value="Não Faturado">Não faturado</option>                                     
      </select>             
   </div>
</div>    
<div class="form-actions">
 <div class="span12">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Alterar</button>
   <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/exportacao" id="btnAdicionar" class="btn"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i> Voltar</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Controller: Exportacao.php
Essa função é adaptada da função "editar individualmente"
A função editarStatus será só para o status, e a outra caso haja algum dado inserido errado, podendo alterar todos seus campos, mas isso já tá resolvido.

```
function editarStatus() {

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->data['custom_error'] = '';

    if ($this->form_validation->run('exportacao') == false) {
        $this->data['custom_error'] = (validation_errors() ? '<div class="form_error">' . validation_errors() . '</div>' : false);
    } else {          
        $data = array(
            'status' => $this->input->post('status')
        );
        if ($this->fatexpo_model->editStatus('exportacao', $data, 'idExportacao', $this->input->post('idExportacao')) == TRUE) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Registro editado com sucesso!');
            redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/exportacao/editarStatus/'.$this->input->post('idExportacao'));
        } else {
            $this->data['custom_error'] = '<div class="form_error"><p>Ocorreu um erro.</p></div>';
        }
    }

    $this->data['result'] = $this->fatexpo_model->getById($this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->data['view'] = 'exportacao/editarExpoStatus';
    $this->load->view('tema/topo', $this->data);

}
```

Model: fatexpo_model.php

```
function editStatus($table,$data,$fieldID,$ID){
    $this->db->where($fieldID,$ID);
    $this->db->update($table, $data);

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() >= 0)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;  
}
```

Na página da minha tabela, eu consigo exibir os ids marcados pelo checkbox dessa maneira:

```
<button onclick='pegaIDs()'>Pegar IDs</button>
<p id='result'></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function pegaIDs(){
      var ids = [];
      $(".check:checked").each(function( index ) {
       ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
      });
      $("#result").html(ids.join('<br />'));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Você tentou fazer um foreach() do $_POST pra editar os que estão marcados?

Comment: @AndréBaill poderia me dar um exemplo por gentileza?

Comment: @AndréBaill consegue ajudar amigo?

Comment: ***Faça da seguinte maneira: Crie um método chamado alterarCheckbox, e coloque o action do seu form para este, e ao receber, fará a atualização de acordo com os selecionados.** Como colocar o action para o form? O método alterarCheckbox é inserido em Controller? Alguém poderia me esclarecer, por favor? @Matheus Madalozzo, como vc fez?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça da seguinte maneira:
Crie um método chamado alterarCheckbox, e coloque o action do seu form para este, e ao receber, fará a atualização de acordo com os selecionados.

```
    // Excluir com checkbox
    public function alterarCheckbox(){

        $ids =  $this->input->post('status');
        $numRegs = count($ids);

        if($numRegs > 0){        

            // atualiza status no banco de dados
            foreach($this->input->post('status') as $valor){
                $dados['status'] = 1;
                $this->db->where('idExportacao', $valor);
                if($this->db->update('exportacao', $dados)){
                    echo $valor." > Atualizado <br>";
                }
            }

        } else {
            echo "Nenhum item foi marcado.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou! Obrigado